# How to animate a transition when navigating to the same Page in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: navigation, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have just 1 page.
When clicking on a Button on the Page, I call Frame.Navigate and navigate to the same page with a Parameter, so the page does something similar but different.

here is my code:  Frame.Navigate(typeof(TheOnlyPage));

For some reason the animation transition is not executed when navigating to the same page like its executed when navigating to another page by defualt.

How do I solve this?

Comment: did u change the RootFrame in the App.cs?

Comment: no, I didnt.   The Frame.Navigation(...) to another Page works perfect with transitions and all. The issue is only when calling the same page.

Answer (score 0):

It may happen if you set NavigationCacheMode to Enabled or Required (this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Enabled/Required;). Check if you have this line in your Page constructor. If so, delete it (so the NavigationCacheMode will be Disabled), and the animation will work.

Answer (score -1):

Use this worked for me. 
It will create a new Instance of the Page and hence should show the animation

```
   Navigationservice.Navigate(new Uri(String.Format("/MainPage.xaml?parameter={0}", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
```

Comment: There is no NavigationService on Windows Phone 8.1 .   This is Windows Phone 8.0 or earlier.

Comment: then its your fault for tagging the question with windows-phone 8 and 8.1 Tag. This simply means you have retargeted a Project from windows-phone 8 silverlight to windowsphone-8.1 silverlight  where its perfectly available.